# How to forward specific local addresses using .forward file

Tags: email, exim

I have an account that recieves email using multiple addresses. I want to redirect some addresses to a different mailbox using the `.forward` file in my home directory, based on the local part. So say I have the email addresses

- person@example.com
- human@example.com
- robot@example.com

I want `human` and `person` to go to my regular mail file, but I want to put mail directed to `robot` in a separate file. I assumed the `.forward` file should be something like this:

```
robot:/home/person/robotmail
```

But this gives a syntax error. I am using exim4.

Comment: Have you tried `save /home/person/robotmail` like the [docs say](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html#SECTsave)? I would probably chose a file in the home of the user and give the other one access to it (simpler to set the permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @sebix for pointing me in the right direction. The resulting `.forward` file:

```
# Exim filter
if $original_local_part is robot then
  save /home/shelvacu/ruby/robotmail/
endif
```

Note that the `# Exim filter` comment is important.